# Getting IoT devices to connect to an authenticated wifi network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, nat, embedded

I have several Internet-of-Things devices such as the Intel Galileo and Raspberry Pi. I'd like to connect these up to the internet obviously, because without it they're just *things*. Unfortunately my university's network requires inputting your account credentials after you connect to the network. This is fine for a laptop, but I have no idea how to do it on an embedded device. Unfortunately, it does the same on the wired network too.

My attempt at a stopgap so far has been (trying) to connect it through my laptop's ethernet port and piggybacking on the wireless. Although I've set up ICS on my Wifi connection to share with my LAN port, and I've set up static IPs on both the laptop and my Galileo, and can even telnet it(!), I can't get the Galileo to ping the outside world from the console. Networks were never my forte.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Laptop is running Windows 7 Home Premium

Answer (score 1):

University networks usually use either WPA-Enterprise or an open network with captive-portal logins.

The former generally is either supported, or (more commonly) isn't. If you need to use WPA-Enterprise but your device doesn't support it, the only way to connect it is through a private WiFi AP that would use regular WPA-PSK and act as a gateway to the main network (usually connected to Ethernet).

With the latter kind, however, everything is handled by the university network's hardware, and the logins are just verified based on the device's MAC address... which is trivially spoofable. So, while I cannot offer anything for Windows, it would be easy to "log in" your devices using a laptop running Linux:

1. Find out your device's MAC address;
2. Set the laptop's WiFi interface to use that address (`ip link set wlan0 addr ab:cd:ef...`)
3. Connect to the WiFi network and log in;
4. Undo the laptop's MAC address change;
5. Tell the actual device to connect to the WiFi network, and it'll be considered "logged in".

Either way, you should talk about this with the network administrators first.